# Gulp src base not changing dest path

Tags: gulp

So, I need to build a script that decompresses zip files from the a file called 'zips', move the unzipped images to a folder called 'src' (really important to keep the same file structure as the 'zips' file) and then, finally, process these images and move them to a folder called 'imgs'.
My unzip task is not keeping the same file structure, and I don't know how to do so, here is my code:

```
gulp.task('unzip', function(){
 return gulp.src('./zips/**/*.{zip,ZIP}', { base: './zips' })
 .pipe(minimatch())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./src'));
});
```